# Details of AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne

Tags: c#, multithreading

1)The call AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne may block client or will definitely block the client?.

2)What is the difference between WaitAll,WaitOne,WaitAny?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. `WaitHandle.WaitOne()` is an instance method that will block until the wait handle is signalled (when the operation is completed). If it has already been signalled previously (i.e. operation already completed) it is possible that the call to `WaitOne()` will not block.
2. `WaitHandle.WaitAll()` and `WaitHandle.WaitAny()` are static methods that allow you to specify a number of wait handles to monitor simultaneously:

   - `WaitHandle.WaitAll()` will wait until *all* of the specified handles have been signalled before it returns.
   - `WaitHandle.WaitAny()` will return as soon as *any* of the specified handles have been signalled.

   These methods allow you to monitor a number of outstanding asynchronous operations at the same time.

*Background:* `AsyncWaitHandle` is the name of a property on the `IAsyncResult` interface. The actual type of this property is `WaitHandle`, which is an abstract base class for types such as `Semaphore`, `Mutex`, and `Manual/AutoResetEvent`.

*See also:* [Blocking Application Execution Using an AsyncWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228962.aspx) (MSDN)

Comment: Before EndInvoke() do we need to call them?

Comment: You're right but I think the OP was asking specifically about AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(). So I think he was asking whether the call to WaitOne would always block even if the async op had completed, which of course it wouldn't

Comment: No. EndInvoke() may be called any time after BeginInvoke() and will block if the operation has not completed yet.

Comment: @threadpool.Calling EndInvoke will block until the async op has completed so you don't need to call WaitOne if you don't wish too. However if you do call WaitOne you still need to call EndInvoke, especially if your async op returns a val etc

Comment: And you should always call EndInvoke otherwise you'll leak resources (the wait handles used internally).

Comment: Your second bullet under number 2 should be WaitHandle.WaitAny(), not WaitOne().

Answer (score 2):

The methods allow you to wait on a windows events. WaitOne is non-static and waits on the event handle for that object. WaitAll and WaitAny are static class-wide methods that wait an a group of event handlers. WaitAll waits for all events to signal and WaitAny for a single event in the group.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'wait on windows events'. WaitOne is primarily used to synchronise asynchronous operations i.e one thread synchronising with another thread. The OP was asking about AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne. AsyncWaitHandle is a WaitHandle typically used to synchronise a BeginInvoke i.e it removes the need for to poll and call IsCompleted on the IAsyncResult

Comment: It can also be used for windows events (e.g. CreateEvent) see SafeWaitHandle property and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safewaithandle.safewaithandle.aspx.