# EventWaitHandle - Difference between WaitAny() and WaitOne()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have 3 threads, two "workers" and one "manager" . The "Workers" threads Waits on `EventWaitHandle` that the "manager" thread will signal the `EventWaitHandle` after that them increase theirs counters.
The only difference between those "worker" threads is that one uses `EventWaitHandle.WaitAny()` and the other one uses `EventWaitHandle.WaitOne()` .

here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MultiThreadedJobs multyThreadedJobs = new MultiThreadedJobs();
        multyThreadedJobs.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();

        multyThreadedJobs.Stop();
    }
}

class MultiThreadedJobs : IDisposable
{
    private EventWaitHandle syncEvent;
    private EventWaitHandle[] syncEventsArray;

    private Thread managerThread;
    private Thread firstWorkerThread;
    private Thread secondWorkerThread;

    private volatile bool running = false;


    public MultiThreadedJobs() // Ctor
    {
        syncEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "JobsSyncEvent");

        syncEventsArray = new EventWaitHandle[1];
        syncEventsArray[0] = syncEvent;

        managerThread = new Thread(ManagerThreadMethod);
        firstWorkerThread = new Thread(FirstWorkerThreadMethod);
        secondWorkerThread = new Thread(SecondWorkerThreadMethod);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        running = true;

        managerThread.Start();
        firstWorkerThread.Start();
        secondWorkerThread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    private void ManagerThreadMethod() // Manager Thread
    {
        while (running)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            syncEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    private void FirstWorkerThreadMethod() // Worker Thread
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (running)
        {
            syncEvent.WaitOne();
            counter++;
        }
    }

    private void SecondWorkerThreadMethod() // Worker Thread
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (running)
        {
            EventWaitHandle.WaitAny(syncEventsArray);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        syncEvent.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem is, The just the second worker thread with the `EventWaitHandle.WaitAny()` always catch the Event, and starving the first worker thread. instead of about 50/50 precent to each of them.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816099/details-of-asyncwaithandle-waitone

Comment: Please show all relevant code, where are you doing `Thread.Start()`?

Comment: @sircodesalot thanks, but i'm not see there any answer for my problem

Comment: @sll, the 'Thread.Start()' exist in another method called Start() .

Comment: @Sll . all relevant code exist here.

Comment: 1) Is this class inherited from `ContextBoundObject` or marked by `Synchronization]` attribute? 2) Are you changing `running` value somewhere?

Comment: @sll , you can see all the code. i edit and added it to the question.

Comment: This is just never going to work, the AutoResetEvent class doesn't promise any fairness.  Ultimately the code makes no sense, there can only ever be one thread that gets signaled with an ARE so there's no point in starting more than one thread.

Comment: @HansPassant ,this code is just an example, the real problem is that just the 'EventWaitHandle.WaitAny()' got signaled. in the real world i have the reason to synchronize it in this way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are looking for a solution to a very common problem in software engineering, the [Producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).  The linked Wikipedia article has decent background info on it, in particular showing how to do it the wrong way.

You are certainly pursuing a solution that's the wrong way.  An AutoResetEvent is far too simplistic.  You've already found one problem with it, it doesn't provide *fairness*.  Many other problems with it, in particular it suffers from a nasty threading race when the producer thread produces jobs faster than the consumer threads.

The sample code is too artificial to offer a good alternative.  Low-level locking can be implemented by the ReaderWriterLock/Slim class.  A class that's particularly well suited to solve producer/consumer problems is the .NET 4 BlockingCollection class.  Supporting an arbitrary number of producer and consumer threads and providing throttling to ensure that a program doesn't blow up when consumers cannot keep up with the producers.  You can rewrite your sample by using a fake "token" that you pass from the producer to the consumer threads.  A `BlockingColletion<bool>` gets the job done.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. in my situation i need to synchronise also `Processes` not just `Threads` , to do this i am using `Named Events`. but i found that this mechanism not give fairness. like you said.
my question is more technically. Why the EventWaitHandle not give fairness? and is there any way to force it to do it more fair ?

Answer (score 6):

The **WaitHandle** class makes it possible for clients to make asynchronous call and wait for: 
a single XML Web service (WaitHandle.WaitOne), 
the first of many XML Web services (WaitHandle.WaitAny), or 
all of many XML Web services (WaitHandle.WaitAll) to return results. 
If you want to process the results as they arrive, you can use the **WaitHandle.WaitAny** method. This method will indicate that one of the operations has completed and will identify the completed operation.

Both the methods are overiddable. And depending on the parameters passed,the implementation varies.For eg,WaitHandle.WaitAny Method (WaitHandle[], Int32, Boolean) waits for any of the elements in the specified array to receive a signal, using a 32-bit signed integer to measure the time interval, and specifying whether to exit the synchronization domain before the wait.

**WaitHandle.WaitOne** Method (Int32, Boolean) when overridden in a derived class, blocks the current thread 
until the current WaitHandle receives a signal, using 32-bit signed integer to measure the time interval and specifying 
whether to exit the synchronization domain before the wait.